# Domain Object? Business Object? Model? Domain Model? What are the differences?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm coding a WebService, and these terms that they use really confuses me. I've done a lot of research and it is still very vague what these terms are.

Comment: From my experience, a Domain Object is an object representation of a Domain Model (such as an object that represents a single row of a database) and Business Objects usually perform some logic on a Domain Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a  [Domain-driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), typically all the terms referring same meaning.

As a general definition, All of them mean that *"a basic component which holds a set of properties related to that domain".*

If you need exact definitions, look this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Core_definitions)